# how to solve InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, exception, casting, changetype

I am trying to get an subarray to convert to the type in 'parameterType' . 'para' is an array of objects. I am getting an invalid cast exception.

I am new to c# and not able to solve this.

```
 object[] param_values = new object[parameterType.Length];
 int k,q = 0;
 int size;
 foreach (ParameterInfo p in parameterType)
 {
     size = Marshal.SizeOf(p.ParameterType);
     object dest = para.Skip(k).Take(size).Cast<object>();
     param_values[q] = Convert.ChangeType(dest, p.ParameterType); // exception occurs here
     k = k + size;
     q++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting multiple objects that you are trying to cast.

`object dest = para.Skip(k).Take(size).Cast<object>();` returns an `IEnumerable<object>` and you cannot cast/changetype it, for example, an `Int32`.

You might try this:

```
object[] param_values = new object[parameterType.Length];
int q = 0;
foreach (object p in para)
{
    param_values[q] = Convert.ChangeType(p, parameterType[q]); 
    q++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am trying to cast multiple objects to a single type. for example object[] = 11, 22, 33, 44. and the parameter type is int32. then the answer should be 1122344. is there any other solution for this?